# Why do STL container adapters require both value and container type as template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Couldn't the first argument `T` be deduced from `Container::value_type`?

Comment: Yes, since C++17 this is possible, for example, see [deduction guides for `std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/deduction_guides).

Answer (score 3):

That would mean that to be used in a container adaptor, a container must provide a nested typedef `value_type`.   Certainly all of the containers in the standard library do so - but that's not the universe of possible containers.

Right now, `stack` requires: Any sequence container supporting operations `back()`, `push_back()` and `pop_back()` can be used to instantiate `stack`.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily true; In the class reference documentation, it is explicitly state that *The container must satisfy the requirements of SequenceContainer*, which include, among other public types, `value_type` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container)

Answer (score 1):

Container adapters are older thst C++ itself.

And they are a neater idea than they are practical.  So they tend to be pretty neglected in my experience.

Plus, some unfortunate ABI choices of major vendors make adding or changing default parameters to templates an ABI breaking issue.

So, we get pre 20th century template arguments and no value_type deduction.

Also, `stack<T>` seems like cleaner syntax than `stack<deque<T>>` anyhow.

Comment: While I agree in principle, their usefulness is mostly beyond the scope of the question, as I was inquiring about any technical/fundamental reason between apparently redundant template arguments. Though your last phrase seems to have provided the most logical explanation for it - it just provides a cleaner syntax.